No ActivityResultRegistryOwner was provided via LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner
I am writing a plugin for an app. I don't have an access to activity context. In my compose view I am calling rememberLauncherForActivityResult but that crashes with
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ActivityResultRegistryOwner was provided via LocalActivityResultRegistryOwner

Is there any way around this?
I found an older SO answer that gave me hopes that there might be a way around it, but it is not working for me. I replaced AmbientContext with LocalContext and that crashes with
my.package.ComposeContext cannot be cast to androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistryOwner
// ComposeContext is just a ContextWrapper implementation to provide correct application context

